# Django Unit Testing A Button (Not Form)

Tags: django, tdd, django-testing, django-tests

Im writing unit tests for a Django package ([Django-Notifications](https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications)) and want to unit test that a notification is deleted when the 'delete' button is pressed.

I know how to test forms:

```
response = self.client.post(
            reverse('webpage'), data={
            'question': 'some question'},
            HTTP_REFERER=referer,
            follow=True
        )
```

And I know how to mock users and sign them in, but have no idea how to unit test non-form buttons =.

More specifically, I dont know how to:

1. Create the mock notification
2. Test that the button successfully removes the notification

(Perhaps this is something that should only be functional tested?)

This is all I have so far:

```
def test_delete_button_removes_notification(self):
        user = User.objects.create_superuser('username')
        self.client.force_login(user)
        # create notification

        # simulate button press

        # assert notification count == 0
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need selenium.

Comment: I use selenium for functional tests. So this needs to be a functional test?

Comment: Unit testing UI is notoriously difficult. Unless you want to test the pure logic of the function I'd use functional testing. To test this as a unit test, you'd need to extract all the view logic (which is practically all of it) into a separate function and test if that function is called under certain conditions, etc.

Comment: @JoostPapendorp thank you very much :)